# Wrong output in function

Tags: python, function, loops, append

Hi I'am totally new to programmering and i have just jumped into it.

The problem i am trying to solve is to make a function that standardized an adress as input.

example:

```
def standardize_address(a):

    numbers =[]
    letters = []
   
    a.replace('_', ' ')
     
    
    for word in a.split():
        if word. isdigit():
            numbers. append(int(word))
        elif word.isalpha():
            letters.append(word)
            
    s = f"{numbers} {letters}"
    
    
    return s
```

Can someone help me explain my error and give me a "pro" programmers solution and "noob" (myself) solution?

This is what i should print:

```
a = 'New_York 10001'
s = standardize_address(a)
print(s)
```

and the output should be:

```
10001 New York
```

Right now my output is:

```
[10001] ['New', 'York']
```

Comment: I got `[10001] []` as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues

- strings are immutable so you need to keep the replace result, so do `a = a.replace('_', ' ')` or chain it before the split call
- You need to concatenate the lists into one `numbers + letters` then join the elements with `" ".join()`
- don't convert the numeric to `int`, that's useless and would force you to convert them back to str in the `" ".join`

```
def standardize_address(a):
    numbers = []
    letters = []
    for word in a.replace('_', ' ').split():
        if word.isdigit():
            numbers.append(word)
        elif word.isalpha():
            letters.append(word)
    return ' '.join(numbers + letters)
```

---

#### Improve

In fact you want to sort the words regarding the `isdigit` condition, so you can express that with a sort and the appropriate sorted

```
def standardize_address(value):
    return ' '.join(sorted(value.replace('_', ' ').split(),
                           key=str.isdigit, reverse=True))
```

Comment: The better way to explain the `replace` issue is to say that Python strings are immutable.  This explains all sorts of cases like this rather than suggesting that the behavior is somewhat a function of the particular method. - good answer though ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very good feedback and i appreciate very much. Enjoy your day :)

Comment: @ThomasR.Hansen you're welcome, you can tihnk about acepting the answer , the green tick on the left

Comment: "@azro. I have done that now. New to the stackoverflow game aswell. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`numbers` and `letters` are both lists of strings, and if you format them they'll be rendered with `[]`s and `''`s appropriately.  What you want to do is to replace this:

```
    s = f"{numbers} {letters}"
    
    
    return s
```

with this:

```
return ' '.join(numbers + letters)
```

`numbers + letters` is the combined list of number-strings and letter-strings, and `' '.join()` takes that list and turns it into a string by putting `' '` between each item.